# How to compute the expected value of a function of a random variable given its log-density function?

Tags: computational-statistics, numerical-integration

Given a log-density function $\mathcal{L}f_{X}(x)$ of an 1d continuous random variable $X \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ and an 1d polynomial function $h: \mathcal{I}(X) \to \mathbb{R}$, the expected value of $h(X)$ is defined as follows:

$$
\mathbb{E}[h(X)] = \int_{\mathcal{I}(X)} h(X)\exp{\mathcal{L}f_{X}(x)}dx  \equiv \int_{\mathcal{I}(X)} h(X)f_{X}(x)dx
$$

However, in many situations, $\exp{\mathcal{L}f_{X}(x)}$ is infinitesimally small and underflow may occurs, making it challenging to compute $\mathbb{E}[h(X)]$.

What are some potential numerically stable solutions to calculate the quantity $\mathbb{E}[h(X)]$?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  As it stands, this question is perhaps too broad for us to handle.  Because underflow is not necessarily an issue, please give us some of the specifics of your actual problem.

Comment: One solution could be a Metropolis–Hastings algorithm which uses only a ratio of the frequencies and $\frac{f(x)}{f(x')} = e^{\log f(x) - \log f(x')}$, which might be reasonably computable even when the frequencies are small. But that is just one out of many potential solutions. I agree that it is broad, and it is difficult to give a definite answer.

Comment: What sort of density would be too small for numerical computation? How about scaling the  variable $X$ such that the density is larger?

Comment: Try taking the log of $h(X)$ and adding it to the log-density before exponentiation.   If the result is still infinitesimally small, then it's a good bet that it wouldn't contribute to the true expected value.